# If B is a dataframe that is a subset of A, how do I remove the entire B dataframe from the A dataframe (in R)

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to remove a dataframe that is a subset of another dataframe: if `B` is a dataframe that is a subset of another dataframe `A`, how do I remove the entire `B` dataframe from `A`?

Reproducible example:

```
A<-data.frame(text = c("Hello I am John","Hello boys","Hello girls","Hello 
   world"), created=c(as.POSIXct("2020-03-18 11:00:29"),as.POSIXct("2020-05- 
   11 11:00:11"),as.POSIXct("2020-01-10 00:00:29"), as.POSIXct("2020-03-19 
   11:11:11")), name=c("John","Anya","Pier","Joe"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

B instead is, e.g., the first and the third rows of A

Comment: Can you share some reproducible example?

Comment: See the `subset` function to keep the records that you want.  E.g., `subset(mtcars, cyl != 4)`

Comment: If you know the row numbers of B you can delete them directly.  E.g.  `NotB <- mtcars[ -c(1, 3) , ]` removes rows 1 and 3 from `mtcars`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be better understood with an example. You need to tests all values so you can use `do.call()` and `paste0()`:

```
#Data
A <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,0),5,5))
B <- A[c(2,4),]

A
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  0  1  0  1
2  0  1  0  1  0
3  1  0  1  0  1
4  0  1  0  1  0
5  1  0  1  0  1

B
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
2  0  1  0  1  0
4  0  1  0  1  0
```

Now, we remove:

```
#Remove
NewA <- A[!do.call(paste0, A) %in% do.call(paste0, B),]
```

Output:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  0  1  0  1
3  1  0  1  0  1
5  1  0  1  0  1
```

It also works with your data:

```
#Data
A<-data.frame(text = c("Hello I am John","Hello boys","Hello girls","Hello world"), created=c(as.POSIXct("2020-03-18 11:00:29"),as.POSIXct("2020-05-11 11:00:11"),as.POSIXct("2020-01-10 00:00:29"), as.POSIXct("2020-03-19 11:11:11")), name=c("John","Anya","Pier","Joe"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
B <- A[c(2,4),]
#Remove
NewA <- A[!do.call(paste0, A) %in% do.call(paste0, B),]
```

Output:

```
             text             created name
1 Hello I am John 2020-03-18 11:00:29 John
3     Hello girls 2020-01-10 00:00:29 Pier
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider a function like this

```
row_matched <- function(df1, df2) {
  stopifnot(
    identical(ncol(df1), ncol(df2)), 
    all(names(df1) == names(df2))
  )
  pos <- mapply(match, df1, df2, list(nomatch = 0L))
  rowSums(!(pos > 0L & pos == pos[, 1L])) < 1L
}
```

Then you can just

```
A[!row_matched(A, B), ]
```

Output

```
         text             created name
2  Hello boys 2020-05-11 11:00:11 Anya
4 Hello world 2020-03-19 11:11:11  Joe
```